# Can't call a nested navigation screen from a deep component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSzITFbOtpQ&list=PLQWFhX-gwJbmmqcP-9zMXBaxQbGKfIJY2&index=3) and created Drawer and Main Tab Navigations for my react native expo app.

Now I need a screen which should not be listed in Drawer or Tab and which is needed to be called from a deep component where navigations props are not being sent.

I tried useNavigation Hook but got error where react native is unable to find any such screen name.

PFB the tentative sample codes:
Main Tab called from App.js

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();
const ListStack = createStackNavigator();

const MainTabScreen = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#fff"
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#009387' }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarColor: '#009387',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarColor: '#1f65ff',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="aperture" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
</Tab.Navigator>
);

export default MainTabScreen;

const HomeStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#009387',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }}>
    <HomeStack.Screen name = "Home" component = {Home}
    options = {{
      title: 'Overview',
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon.Button name="menu" size={25}
        backgroundColor="#009387" onPress={()=>navigation.openDrawer()} 
        ></Icon.Button>
        )
    }}
    />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);

const ProfileStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <ProfileStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#d02860',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }}>
    <ProfileStack.Screen name = "Profile" component = {Profile}
    options = {{
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon.Button name="menu" size={25}
        backgroundColor="#d02860" onPress={()=>navigation.openDrawer()} 
        ></Icon.Button>
        )
    }}
    />
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>
);

const ListStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <NotificationsStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#694fad',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }}>
    <ListStack.Screen name = "List" component = {List}
    options = {{
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon.Button name="menu" size={25}
        backgroundColor="#694fad" onPress={()=>navigation.openDrawer()} 
        ></Icon.Button>
        )
    }}
    />
  </NotificationsStack.Navigator>
);
```

useNavigation component section:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
.
.
.
const SomeStuff = ({item}) => {
......
<ListButton title={Count} screenName="ListStackScreen" />
.....
}
.
.

function ListButton({ title, screenName }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title={`${title} Total`}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(screenName)}
    />
  );
}
```

also tried:

```
navigation.navigate('HomeDrawer',{screen: screenName})
```

I need to call the above ListStackScreen from a deep component. I tried using navigation.navigate(ListStackScreen) but it doesn't work as explained above.
Please let me know how to use the screen without displaying it in any Drawer or Tab visually.

Edit: Update after trying the given answer
[image]
I do have this in the main app.js also:

```
<Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={MainTabScreen} />
```

Comment: Can you show how you tried to implement useNavigation?

Comment: @MichaelBahl I have updated the same in the question. Please check.

Comment: You nor added ListStackScreen to a tab screen or to an Stacknavigator.

Comment: @MichaelBahl Didn't add to Tab screen because I do not want to show it on the Tab drawer menu. I need to not include it in menu but still be able to Navigate that screen from any other deep component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup should allow you to navigate between HomeStackScreen and ListStackScreen.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeStackScreen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomeStackScreen"
        component={HomeStackScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ListStackScreen"
        component={ListStackScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="HomeStack">
        <Tab.Screen
          name="HomeStack"
          component={HomeStack}
          }}
        />
    …
```

You can nest stacknavigator into Drawer, the inner stacknavigator screen won‘t be shown in Drawer.

I have created an [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/nest-stack-into-drawer)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried it and now I have 2 menu bars as updated in the question. I do have the main Drawer in app.js and remaining stuff in Tab Screen. As I am new to react native, please let me know if there is any way to use this in <Tab.Navigator> and <Tab.Screen> section...

Comment: As you can see in my sample I disabled the second navigation bar `headerShown: false`.

Comment: @MicaelBahl Thanks. It's working now. Have marked this as answer. I'm facing a small glitch though further. Once I go to ListStackScreen from deep component, then go to a different tab menu and then press the home tab menu, then the ListStackScreen is still shown here. I have to click Home menu tab twice to load the HomeStackScreen. Any further guidance is much appreciated....

Comment: That’s the default behavior I think you should not override this.
Nevertheless you can set Tab.Screen->options->unmountOnBlur->true to override this behavior and set the StackNavigator to initial screen.

Comment: @MichaleBahl This OnBlur stuff is not working... However thinking to keep it the default behaviour way...